# Modify set of data using Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file containing a set of data as follow....

```
F4|Apple
B7|Orange
E4|Pear
GT|Grape
EE|Raisin
H6|Banana
```

Using notepad++ how can I convert this data so it looks like....

```
Apple|F4
Orange|B7
Pear|E4
Grape|GT
Raisin|EE
Banana|H6
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the *Replace* tab of the find dialog (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) select the *Regular Expression* option then

Find what: `^(.*)\|(.*)$`

Replace With: `$2|$1`

Comment: Perfect,  I already had something similar but I had neglected to select the Regular Expression option :)